# jQuery .load() function works only after applying php include

Tags: php, jquery, function, load

Something strange is happening using jquery `.load()` function.

```
$('#divR').load('clock01.html');
```

Nothing happens - many times. Or, just a part of the file is loaded, but it is scattered around the screen.

Then I tried inside `#divR`:

`<?php include "clock01.html"?>`  // always works ok

And then again

`$('#divR').load('clock01.html');` //always works, but only after `php include`

Tested about 10 times, without exception. What could be the reason ?

I regularly cleared the browser cache, each time.

Comment: Really hard to give a helpful answer without the source code of the javascript and the contents of clock01.html

Comment: Make sure .load() is executed when dom is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some possibility's 
first check your error console using  `F12` or `cntrl+sift+j`
  1. Have u declared `div` with same id like 'divR'
  2. Do you included `jquery` lib ?

u put  block after html put after a page not after html

Comment: I checked everything. You can see the whole story on `www.zokam.22web.org`. Click on `Clock` and then `Next` button. Please check.

Comment: 1.st why u put <script> block after html put after a page not after html

Comment: Anant, you solved the problem. I move `body` and `html` after `</script>` and it works. Thanks a lot. Could you place some answer, pls, so I could accept it.